# Data types returned by dbGetQuery

Tags: sql, r, rjdbc

I am using dbGetQuery to fetch and insert data in a SQL server. I am trying to understand if or not dbGetQuery applies some sort of data categorization algorithms by default.

The object  `x <-dbGetQuery(dbhandle, SQL_stored_procedure)`  returns a data frame. What I am finding is in some instances some columns in the databases are being considered as character and different in another instance. 
The datatype is defined as varchar(15) in SQL.

Is this possible? Has anyone else encountered similar problems?